# Using holoeverywhere

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I am trying to install holoeverywhere to ADT using instructions from

https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/wiki/Import-in-IDE#eclipse

Unfortunately this ends with:

> No valid Android XML Editor Delegate found for file /HoloEverywhere
>   Addon
>
> The POM for com.google.android:support-v4:jar:r13 is missing, no
>   dependency information available

And hundreds of other similar errors. I tried it several times from scratch, doesn't help. I suspect installation steps changed again... Is anyone able to help?

Comment: Nope (or not aware), just plain standard Google-provided bundled Eclipse+ADT

Comment: Which steps of the guide have you followed to install holoeverywhere?

Comment: Exactly these, starting with #eclipse anchor:

https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/wiki/Import-in-IDE#eclipse

reading until "IntelliJ IDEA"

Answer (score 6):

I just successfully installed HoloEverywhere on ADT, and this is what I did:

Part I

- Import the project from git following [this instructions](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/wiki/Import-in-IDE#eclipse)  (for protocol use git)
- This will create four new projects in your package explorer: HoloEverywhere Addon Preferences, HoloEverywhere Addon Slider, HoloEverywhere Demo and HoloEverywhere Library. Leave open just the last one.
- remove HoloEverywhere/ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock/libs/android-support-v4.jar
- Copy HoloEverywhere/library/libs/android-support-v4-r13.1.jar to
  HoloEverywhere/ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock/libs/
- on Eclipse mark the Holoeverywhere Library project as Android library(is Library).

Part II

- File->import->Existing Android Code into Workspace. Import "HoloEverywhere/ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock/".
  Now you have actionbarsherlock as a new project in your Package Explorer
- On Eclipse mark this project as Android library(is Library).
- On HoloEverywhere Library project Android properties add actionbarsherlock as library.

Part III

- On your Android project  properties add "HoloEveryWhere Library" project as library.

Part IV

- Enjoy!

Comment: Sounds promising, but do you know what shall I do if I have already ABS in my project?

Comment: I think you can uncheck your current ABS as library from your project, and check it in the Holoeverywhere project. Then mark the HoloEverywhere as library in your project.

Comment: i find myself needing to do this quite a lot, its a jar mismatch error i think.

Answer (score 1):

The project `holoeverywhere` developers sometimes change project instructions, locations, etc. for better adaptting to platforms *like eclipse*.

You may have all possible problems as other people do, so in `github` there are lot of fixes and answers. Here is the link:
[HoloEverywhere issues](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues?page=1&state=closed)