# Change background color of edittext in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

If I change the background color of my `EditText` using the below code, it looks like the box is shrunken and it doesn't maintain the ICS theme of a blue bottom border that exists for a default `EditText`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#99000000"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id_nick_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"  
    />
    <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
             android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
             android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/id_nick_name">  
        <Button 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="add"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
         <Button 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="cancel"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Image of EditText]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you should do is to create a 9 patch image for edittext and set that image as edit text background. You can create 9 patches using [this](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) website

I am attaching a sample 9 patch image for your reference.Use it as edittext background and you will get an idea.Right click the image and select "save image as". When you save the image dont forget to give its extension as "9.png"

[image]

Comment: cool, it works like as i expected only thing is. i just need to change the image as per my requirement. thanks

Answer (score 42):

one line of lazy code:

```
mEditText.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: This works great for tinting the background across both Holo and Material Design and is easy to implement.  Thanks!  This should probably be the accepted answer - it preserves the original background of the view and its dimensions, while changing its colour.

Comment: you are THE lifesaver!

Comment: This works, but the other edittexts in my app keep this color

Comment: @GeorgianBenetatos you should mutate the drawable before changing it if you only want to alter a specific instance: http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html

Answer (score 22):

Here the best way

First : make new `xml` file in `res`/`drawable` name it `rounded_edit_text` then paste this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#F9966B" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

Second: in res/layout  copy and past following code (code of `EditText`)

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtdoctor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text"
    android:ems="10" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: you can change solid color to the color you need

Comment: Please help me to know, how the layout reads the drawable file ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

I create color.xml file, for naming my color name (black, white...)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
 </resources>
```

And in your EditText, set color

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="asdsadasdasd"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:background="@color/white"
        />
```

or use style
in you style.xml:

```
<style name="EditTextStyleWhite" parent="android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

and add ctreated style to EditText:

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="asdsadasdasd"
        style="@style/EditTextStyleWhite"
        />
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution I have found is to change the background color programmatically. This does *not* require dealing with any 9-patch images:

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_nick_name)).getBackground()
    .setColorFilter(Color.<your-desi‌​red-color>, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Source: [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6749675/1839209)

Comment: you're missing .getBackground()
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_nick_name)).getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.<your-desired-color>, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

Answer (score 1):

The color you are using is white  "#ffffff" is white so try a different one change in the values if you want until you get your need from this link [Color Codes](http://www.color-hex.com/color-names.html)
  and it should go fine

Answer (score 0):

You should use style instead of background color. Try searching holoeverywhere then I think this one will help you solve your problem

[Using holoeverywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885019/using-holoeverywhere)

just change some of the 9patch resources to customize the edittext look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

For me this code it work
So put this code in XML file rounded_edit_text

> `<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
>       <item>
>         <shape
>           android:shape="rectangle">
>               <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#3498db" />
>               <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />
>               <padding
>                   android:left="5dp"
>                   android:top="5dp"
>                   android:right="5dp"
>                   android:bottom="5dp"    >
>               </padding>
>           </shape>
>      </item>
>   </layer-list>`

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a working solution to this problem after 2 days of struggle, below solution is perfect for them who want to change few edit text only, change/toggle color through java code, and want to overcome the problems of different behavior on OS versions due to use setColorFilter() method.

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import com.newco.cooltv.R;

public class RqubeErrorEditText extends AppCompatEditText {

  private int errorUnderlineColor;
  private boolean isErrorStateEnabled;
  private boolean mHasReconstructedEditTextBackground;

  public RqubeErrorEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initColors();
  }

  public RqubeErrorEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initColors();
  }

  public RqubeErrorEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initColors();
  }

  private void initColors() {
    errorUnderlineColor = R.color.et_error_color_rule;

  }

  public void setErrorColor() {
    ensureBackgroundDrawableStateWorkaround();
    getBackground().setColorFilter(AppCompatDrawableManager.getPorterDuffColorFilter(
        ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), errorUnderlineColor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
  }

  private void ensureBackgroundDrawableStateWorkaround() {
    final Drawable bg = getBackground();
    if (bg == null) {
      return;
    }
    if (!mHasReconstructedEditTextBackground) {
      // This is gross. There is an issue in the platform which affects container Drawables
      // where the first drawable retrieved from resources will propogate any changes
      // (like color filter) to all instances from the cache. We'll try to workaround it...
      final Drawable newBg = bg.getConstantState().newDrawable();
      //if (bg instanceof DrawableContainer) {
      //  // If we have a Drawable container, we can try and set it's constant state via
      //  // reflection from the new Drawable
      //  mHasReconstructedEditTextBackground =
      //      DrawableUtils.setContainerConstantState(
      //          (DrawableContainer) bg, newBg.getConstantState());
      //}
      if (!mHasReconstructedEditTextBackground) {
        // If we reach here then we just need to set a brand new instance of the Drawable
        // as the background. This has the unfortunate side-effect of wiping out any
        // user set padding, but I'd hope that use of custom padding on an EditText
        // is limited.
        setBackgroundDrawable(newBg);
        mHasReconstructedEditTextBackground = true;
      }
    }
  }

  public boolean isErrorStateEnabled() {
    return isErrorStateEnabled;
  }

  public void setErrorState(boolean isErrorStateEnabled) {
    this.isErrorStateEnabled = isErrorStateEnabled;
    if (isErrorStateEnabled) {
      setErrorColor();
      invalidate();
    } else {
      getBackground().mutate().clearColorFilter();
      invalidate();
    }
  }
}
```

Uses in xml

```
<com.rqube.ui.widget.RqubeErrorEditText
            android:id="@+id/f_signup_et_referral_code"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/referral_iv"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/referral_iv"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/lbl_referral_code"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_sp_16"
            android:theme="@style/EditTextStyle"/>
```

Add lines in style

```
<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/txt_color_change</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/et_default_color_text</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/et_default_color_rule</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/et_engagged_color_rule</item>
  </style>
```

java code to toggle color

```
myRqubeEditText.setErrorState(true);
myRqubeEditText.setErrorState(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my working solution

```
View view = new View(getApplicationContext());
view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.background);
myEditText.setBackground(view.getBackground());
```